# Scrolling wheel encoder with button push button action into wheel axis

Tags: encoder, button, rotary, wheel

I am looking for a wheel that you can push into as a button as well as scroll indefinitely in either direction.

Here's the exact part I am talking about. I'm not sure exactly what it is called.

[image: Image of scrolling wheel with click]

The ultimate goal is to be able to tell a direction of the scroll and how fast the scroll is in order to cycle through options and to be able to press into the wheel to confirm a selection.

I've found so far something called a ["Rotary B Click"](https://www.mikroe.com/rotary-b-click) which indefinitely scrolls in either direction and has a button but the button action is in the wrong direction (towards the board instead of towards the wheel axis). It also seems that it is a rather large component, I am looking for something smaller.

I also found [this component(potentiometer)](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ALPS/RK14J11R000H?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtC25l1F4XBUza7emsVrz94TFm2uiKXRZw%3D) which only rotates once and doesn't click but visually looks close to the component I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Editing your question to make it clear that you are looking for the correct search terms, etc., is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try searching for "thumbwheel encoder". A number of hits look promising, such as [this](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electric%20Works%20PDFs/EVQWK.pdf) one (not in stock so you will probably have to keep looking for yourself).

[image]

Electrically it's just a normal mechanical quadrature encoder with a mechanical push switch, so a standard firmware/hardware approach would work, perhaps tweaked for the amount of bounce and number of detents or steps.